# Connecting From PHP Server to MySQL Server on Amazon AWS

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, connection, internal

I have two servers setup on Amazon AWS. One server is running PHP and the other has MySQL. I can connect to the MySQL database through my terminal and MySQL Query Browser.

I am trying to get a connection between the PHP and MySQL servers.

Here is the PHP Code that I am using (works for "localhost" databases)

```
$dbbase = 'mydb';               
$dbuser = 'myuser';         // Your MySQL username
$dbpass = 'mypassword';     // ...and password
$dbhost = 'localhost:3306';  // Internal IP for MYSQL Server

// connect to database
$dblink = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) 
    or die ("System Down");

mysql_select_db($dbbase, $dblink) 
    or die ("Database Down");
```

It is my understanding that I should be able to route this an internal AWS traffic, but at this point I will take anything that works and build from there.

Here is what I have done:

- Added the ip of the PHP server to the Security Group for MySQL(3306) permissions
- Tried to use the internal, external, and private IPs/DNSs of the MySQL Server as the $dbhost variable
- Created myuser@% (wildcard) on thy MySQL server

Any ideas or tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to hit the mysql machine from the PHP machine on 3306? Try this command: `telnet <mysql_host_external_IP> 3306`. See if it works.

Comment: When I do 'telnet' it says "command not found". I tried 'ping' but it just sits there and nothing happens till it times out.

Comment: I opened ICMP in the security groups and now I can ping the MySQL server form the PHP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got this working.

I think the big trick was to add this rule to the Security Group:

> Type: MySQL
>
> Source: 10.0.0.0/8

My understanding is that 10.0.0.0/8 covers all internal amazon IPs. I think you could tighten this up, but it is possible for the internal IP of your servers to change, so that would need to be managed.

Then in my PHP script I used the Private DNS of my MySQL Server. It should look something like this: `ip-10-10-100-100.ec2.internal:3306`

In the end, I think that is everything that I did.

Comment: It's better to use security groups for internal AWS-to-AWS rules. If you have a MySQL security group and a PHP security group, the MySQL security group should accept inbound traffic from the PHP group on 3306.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue - turns out MySQL extension for PHP is NO longer included in PHP5!

"In PHP 5 (updated PHP 5.0.4), the following changes exist. Built in: DOM, LibXML, Iconv, SimpleXML, SPL and SQLite. And the following are no longer built in: MySQL and Overload."

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php